# Reading a file where the user has to provide some parameters

Tags: c++

OK so i know the question is a bit confusing (dont downvote right away, let me explain...)

I have a text file like this:

```
dim
coins
oponent
```

I want to read this text file but while reading it, ask the user for specific responses, for example:

`"reads line with the word dim" -> asks user the dimensions -> next line -> "reads line with coins" -> asks user how many coins and so forth until the EOF.`

Is there anyway to do this? if yes, can you show me how?

Thanks and plz dont downvote, just tell me what's wrong and i will edit the post..

EDIT: This is the way i'm reading the file and asking the user input

```
void LeitorFich::lerFicheiro(string nomeFich)
{
    int i, j, t;
    string linha, nome, nome1;
    ifstream fich(nomeFich);

while(getline(fich, linha))
{
    istringstream iss(linha);

    iss >> nome;

    if(nome == "dim")
    {
        cout << nome << " ";
        iss >> i >> j;
    }
}
cin.get();

fich.close();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you code what you have just described, take input, based on input ask user the question.

Comment: @ShamimHafiz i tried that but when i give the dimensions, it stops reading the file.

Comment: Can you post what you have coded so far.

Comment: The required effort is what have you tried? and What wrong you get? If you get no error why you ask then?

Comment: @ShamimHafiz Just edited

Comment: @Raindrop7 there is no error, the values go where they are supposed to but it stop in dim, it doesnt reach the other 2 parameters

Comment: The only "asking for input" going on in this loop is a single character fetch per loop iteration which ends up being discarded. And fyi read  why [`while(!fich.eof())` is wrong **here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: Do this instead: `while(getline(fich, linha))`

Comment: ^^^ ...and remove the stand-alone `getline` invoke in the loop. I.e. *move* that to be the loop condition rather than ignoring whether it failed or not.

Comment: What do you want from "stringstream" here?

Comment: @Raindrop7 i want it to read the entire text file while letting the user input some parameters

Comment: `iss >> i >> j` This tries to read the two integer values from the line just read.

Comment: **Always** check *after* reading that the read was successful, e.g.: `if (in >> x >> y) { use(x, y); } else { deal_with_failed_read(); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example will look like this:

Consider I have a file called "test.txt" which contains the very content as yours

```
string sLine;

ifstream inFile("test.txt");

int Dim1, Dim2, coins, oponent;

while(inFile >> sLine ){
    if("dim" == sLine){
        std::cout << "Dim1: ";
        std::cin >> Dim1;
        std::cout << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Dim2: ";
        std::cin >> Dim2;
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    else
        if("coins" == sLine){
            std::cout << "coins: ";
            std::cin >> coins;
        }
    else
        if("oponent" == sLine){
            std::cout << "oponent: ";
            std::cin >> oponent;
        }
}

inFile.close();
```

Comment: so i dont need to use the getline()?

Comment: Yes as long as your words are not separated by white spaces: `dim, coins,...`